Best way to deal with Nulls in python
Background: I have a Python data frame with some null values.  I'm trying to impute the value of the nulls in a repeatable/automated way.
Details: I have a data frame of inflation values for 2000 products in 150 countries.   Unfortunately, I have a lot of null values. I can assume that inflation across countries is perfectly correlated. So I'm looking to impute my missing values using both the real inflation column but also my product and country column.
Ask: How do I fill in the null values in my data frame?  I want the function/algorithm that considers the other countries and products when it imputes the values. For example, if country A had products in common with country B and the products in B were always twice the inflation rate, then any gap in B could be calculated by doubling the rate of the similar product in country A. I don't know the best way to do this in Python.

Just to confirm: did you search SO first, and you found no answers whatsoever relating to nulls in data frames?

The .fillna() method is used for replacing NA values with some default, e.g. 0.

.fillna() can fill in a value like zero or previous values or median, but I'm not looking at this.  I'm hoping to do something better.  Since I know the products are correlated, I'm trying to use this to fill in the missing values.

If you want to replace the nulls with other values, then do that.  What is the difficulty?  Do you not know how to find the nulls?  Do you not know what values to use as replacements?

some example source data and what the result should or could look like would really help this Question! you can always fill with the average or mean of some data or interpolate between adjacent data. etc., but there's no general solution to data filling

If I understand your intentions right, sklearn.impute module is what you should check:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html
Especially the section 6.4.3. Multivariate feature imputation
The code there looks exactly like what you describe in your countries example

The answer to this question is highly data dependent. Do you really observe a pattern in inflation across countries and year. maybe you can use the average of last five years for same country , the cross-sectional mean or median as the imputed value. maybe you can segregate the countries into developed and developing and fill the corresponding mean or median values for the missing values.
Intuitively, You are just trying to model the null values and trying to predict from the model . everything depends on how good and realistic your model is.
